# How to send the error message alert in Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, exception, datatable

I am using the JQuery Data Table in mvc format. Binding the JQuery data table, using condition. But i don't know how to else the condition , show the error message. I need to show the error alert message server side are client side. My sample Code:

```
 public ActionResult Action(string EmpNo)
        {
            if (condition)
            {
               // data table passing
            }
            else
            {
                //here how to show the error message client side or server side 
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can return a JavascriptResult. [JavaScriptResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
return Javascript("yourJS COde");
```

some thing like this

```
public ActionResult TestJavaScript() {
    string s = "$('#divResultText').html('JavaScript Passed');";
    return JavaScript(s);
}
```

Comment: But i am using datatable so that not aceeptable

Comment: we using the jauery data table in client side we only need send the error in datatable formate

Answer (score 0):

You should return `JsonResult` with an arbitrary object (or real object, if you've created one) matching the expected return signature for DataTables.  Something like:

```
var result = // do something, get a list of stuff etc

return new JsonResult {
    // `Data` is the thing that turns into your json response
    Data = new {
        error = result.Success ? "" : result.Message,
        fieldErrors = new bool[0], // just to fake an empty array
        data = new bool[0],
        aaData = result.Success ? result.Items.Select(o => new {
            //use arbitrary column names if you've specified them in config with `aoColumns` and `mDataProp`, see comment below
            OrderID = o.ID,
            ChannelID = o.Partner,
            ReferenceKey = o.PartnerReferenceKey,
            o.CustomerEmail,
            Status = o.Status.ToString(),
            Value = o.Total,
            CreatedOn = o.CreatedOn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), // provide in interpretable format
        }) : (object) new bool[0], // must return an empty list in order for it to understand errors
        iTotalRecords = result.TotalCount,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = result.TotalCount, // should be different if filtering
        sEcho // this is provided by the request, not sure what it means...
    }
};
```

For custom column names from the ajax response, you'll want to review:

- http://datatables.net/blog/Extended_data_source_options_with_DataTables
- http://datatables.net/beta/1.8/examples/ajax/objects.html